# Java Generic (List<T> list1) VS (List<? super SuperClass> list2)

Tags: generics

Q. why first one is not working, but second is working fine.?

```
1
public List<? extends Animal> doAdd(List<? extends Animal> list) {
    //here unable to add, compilation error
    list.add(new Cat());
    return list;
}

2
private static <T> List<T> doAdd(List<T> list){
    //working fine.
    ls.add((T) new Cat());
    return ls;
}
List<Animal> list = new ArrayList<Aninal>();
doAdd(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

`? extends Sometype` doesn't allow you to add anything other than `null`.`? extends Sometype` is to allow us to refer to subtype.

Let's take an example

```
List<? extends Animal> list = new ArrayList<Dog>(); // this assignment works because of ? extends Animal and Dog is a subtype of Animal

list.add(new Cat()); // this will give a compiler error
```

but assume if add() worked, you would be able add `Cat` to a list of `Dog` which would defeat the idea of compile time checks that generics provide.That's why `? extends Sometype` prevents you from adding anything other than `null`

In the second case, you need a cast because the method itself doesn't know what `T` would be , so `ls.add((T) new Cat());`  would fail without a cast.

you can update the second method definition to allow `add()` to work without cast.

```
private static  List<? super Animal> doAdd(List<? super Animal> list){

        list.add(new Cat());
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: in second case it's allowing to add, but still need to cast/or use super class ref variable at the time of retrieval. so why not in first case allowing add()?

Comment: @user13090 `? extends Type` doesn't allow you to add anything other than `null` , with `? super Type` retrieval type will be `Object`